# installing pydev or PDT without JDT

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-pdt

I've been spending a little time trying to see how bare bones an Eclipse install I could get. I've found that the available packages tend to have things that I don't really need, and since eclipse is all about plugins, I figure that I can just start with a minimal set and install needed ones as I go.

To that end, I downloaded the platform runtime binary from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/
and started experimenting. My usual plugins installed fine, but I've run into a few annoyances in installing language plugins. Namely, they all seem to depend on the JDT plugin somehow. Installing Pydev from their update site pulls in JDT, along with a bunch of other cruft without explicitely depending on it, while trying to install PDT, from either the Juno repository or the PDT update site simply fails until I install the JDT.

Is there any way to install such plugins without JDT, eclipse being eclipse and all? Am I going about this completely wrong? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PDT depends on JDT. If you look at [the source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/.classpath) of PDT, you can see the following in .classpath file:

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
```

The .classpath file contains information that it uses to create the classpath used at build-time, runtime etc. I think this is fundamentally true for any plug-in project.